# Check for xpath duplicates while running a for loop in scrapy for python

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm scraping xml data through scrapy and at the same time I want to check on duplicates. For this I'm using the following code:

```
    arr = []

    for tr in response.xpath('/html/body/table[1]'):
        if tr.xpath('tr/td/text()').extract() not in arr:
           arr.append(tr.xpath('tr/td/text()').extract()) 

    print arr
```

This yields the following output (demo data):

```
[[u'test1', u'12', u'test2', u'12', u'test1', u'12', u'test2', u'12']]
```

But I want to have the following output:

```
[[test1, 12, test2, 12]]
```

So, I want to get rid of the duplicates. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Tnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
list(
    chain(
    *list(
        { e : 1 for e in list(zip_longest(*([iter(tr)] * 2), fillvalue=''))}.keys()
    )))
```

It creates an iterable over the same list duplicated, so it mixes elements of both. Then I use a dictionary comprehension to remove duplicated tuples generated from `zip_longest()`. `chain` flattens values inside tuples and `list()` exhaust the iterable.

I do mock the result of your `xpath` command, due to you have not provided a complete example that works.

```
from itertools import zip_longest, chain

#tr = response.xpath('/html/body/table[1]')
tr = ['test1', '12', 'test2', '12', 'test1', '12', 'test2', '12']

l = list(
    chain(
    *list(
        { e : 1 for e in list(zip_longest(*([iter(tr)] * 2), fillvalue=''))}.keys()
    ))) 
print(l)
```

It yields:

```
['test2', '12', 'test1', '12']
```

Comment: Tnx for your comment, but this yields the following error: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: @user2237168: Sorry, I didn't test my code, but I hope you get the idea. Your `xpath` returns a list, so, traverse it and save each item in the dictionary as a key, and it will filter out by itself repeated elements, like: `for elem in tr.xpath('tr/td/text()').extract(): d[elem] = 1`

Comment: Once more, tnx for your comment. However, the problem is that I want to output 2 values next to one another like the following: if I have `['test1', '12', 'test2', '12', 'test1', '12', 'test2', '12']` the output must be

`test1, 12
test2, 12`

Sorry for that, I see that I posted the wrong structure in my question, hope you still could help me. Tnx alot for your time. I modified my question as well

Comment: @user2237168: I've edited the answer to try to solve your problem. I've done now a complete example with expected output.

Comment: I know, I can't provide you with the "real" website I need to scrape as it contains sensitive information. Anyway, I really appreciate your time for thinking along and providing me with new information.